# Return numeric pattern with function parameter as its length

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to return numeric pattern using a function and function has parameter `length`.

This is what i tried,

```
export const numericPattern = (length: number) => /[\d]{length}/;
```

I just want to return the pattern with given length and if length is not given as parameter, i need to return only `/[\d]/`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const numericPattern = (length) => {
  const tail = length ? "{" + length + "}" : "";
  return new RegExp(`[\\d]${tail}`);
};

console.log(numericPattern(1)); // -> /[\d]{1}/
console.log(numericPattern()); //  -> /[\d]/
```

Comment: Testing whether `length` is *falsy* will work in many cases, but by doing it this way you deny the user the possibility to look for `0` repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
function rx(l){
 return new RegExp("[\\d]"+(l===undefined?"":`{${l}}`),"g");
}

const tst=["7864","abc"],
      larr=[undefined,0,1,3];

tst.forEach(t=>{
 console.log("String:",t);
 larr.forEach(l=>{
  let r=rx(l);
  console.log(l,r.toString(),t.match(r));
 })
});
```